# Using unit fractions as building blocks for real numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, soft-question, real-numbers

This is a soft question so please bear with me.

There are several ways to introduce real numbers. Positional system (decimal for example) is the most common one, another way is through continued fractions, and other ways exist.

However (like in both of these examples) integers and non-integers (rationals and irrationals) are treated differently, for example in the positional system there's a point necessary to separate the integer and the fractional part of the number (i.e. 3.14159), in a simple continued fraction representation the integer part is also written separately.

---

On the other hand, if we use unit fractions, we can represent almost all the real numbers in a unified way as a sum of unit fractions. (Zero is an exception, but here I only consider *positive* numbers).

**Advantages:**

- All rational numbers can be written as a finite sum of distinct unit fractions. One way is through the greedy algorithm (then the integers $N$ will all begin with truncated harmonic series, until $H_k <N$ for some $k=k(N)$, the rest will be expanded by the greedy algorithm in the usual sense).

For example:

$$2=\sum_{k=2}^{10} \frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{230}+\frac{1}{57960}$$

- Rational numbers can be written as an infinite sum of distinct unit fractions as well (I'm not sure if any rational number can be written that way, but I think so).

For example:

$$1=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k}$$

- All irrational numbers can be written as an infinte sum of distinct unit fractions. We can also do it using the greedy algorithm or in various other ways.

**Disadvantages:**

- The representation is not unique. Any number can be represented as a sum of an infinite number of distinct unit fractions in a multitute of ways (probably in an infinite number of ways) and even most rationals allow mutliple egyptian fraction representations.
- Results of arithmetic operations will not be immediately represented in a canonical way (addition and multiplication can lead to some identical denominators, subtraction and especially division will require a lot of work to get back to the original representation). However, continued fractions also do not allow simple arithmetic, they are arguably even worse in that regard.
- We need to take special care to separate the infinite unit fractions series which converge to some real number from the divergent series, like the harmonic series.
- In any case, we need to introduce the integers and their arithmetic operations first, otherwise we will not be able to do arithmetics with the unit fractions (even if we formally introduce them first, instead of the integers).

---

The questions:

> Is there any number theory or real analysis course which discusses this representation of the real numbers in depth?
>
> Are there other advantages or disadvantages for this representation when compared to the common ones?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction